# Password_verify() gives true if the pwd is contained in the string to parse

Tags: php

I got a problem since a couple of days about password_verify(). I didn't notice it before failing when entering the password in my url.

To explain, I am developing a webservice and to authenticate I need to use password and ID in my request URL.

This is my code

```
 if ($stmt->prepare("SELECT hashedPWD FROM `user` WHERE `id` = ?")){ // Trying to get the hashed pwd stored in DB
            $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($pwdHash); // $pwdHash contains the password hashed by password_hash() when the account was created
            $stmt->fetch();
            $stmt->close();
        }
$password = "test"; // The password in URL which is the good one
$isPwdGood = password_verify($password, $pwdHash);

var_dump($isPwdGood); // returns true, seems good right there

$password = "testtttttttttt"; // contains the real password with some others characters
  
$isPwdGood = password_verify($password, $pwdHash);

var_dump($isPwdGood); // returns also true
```

The problem here is that when I want to confirm the identity of my client, I need to be sure that the password is the one he gives me but with password_verify() I can get a bad password which contains the real one and it will work.

Comment: Output all the compared values and see.

Comment: The first $password get "test"
The second $password get "testtttttttttt"

$isPwdGood gives true for both.

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue: https://3v4l.org/2YM0Y - If that happens to you, then there's something else going on here that we can't see. Also, don't send passwords in URL's. If you can't use POST, then at least put it in as a header.

Comment: Check your columns varchar length?

Comment: @AaronNoHuanKnows - That would cause an opposite issue, making all tests fail (since the hash would be invalid).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Right, i misunderstood the issue, my bad!

Comment: The column where you store the hash must be at least VARCHAR(60)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys i just found out the answer to my problem.

I wasn't watching the whole process of creating an account and I should have done that because I just saw that the function used is crypt() and (I don't know why) it didn't work well with previous salt and hashed password.

I tried to switch to the function I showed you which is password_hash() and it worked better !

Thanks you all guys for helping me I appreciate.